# Unable to run basic Angular 2 App

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am trying to setup Angular App using angular CLI by following the steps mentioned in angular website.

But when I use ng serve command and try to open the url http://localhost:4200/

It is stuck in loading screen forever.

Steps followed for Setup:

1) Installed Node Js

2) npm install -g typescript

3) npm install -g @angular/cli

4) ng new PROJECT_NAME

5) cd PROJECT_NAME

6) ng serve

in chrome developer tools Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined is being shown.

Pls Help.Thanks in Advance

Comment: You need to add files such as package.json systemjs.config.js and then perform npm isntall and then npm serve. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html

Comment: What is the error in the console?

Comment: Tried this and it works for me. Try to open web developer tools and see if you get any errors.

Comment: First make sure you have installed Node 6.9.0 or higher and then after step 3, use `ng help` or `ng -v` to check successful installation and version.

Comment: in chrome developer tools Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined is being shown.

Comment: I have checked the installation using ng -v.It has been installed properly.

Comment: Is this an absolute blank app or do you have some code? if so post it

Comment: @user3762635 what is your node version?

Comment: Node version is 6.10.0 and I didnt add any code to the app.I have just executed  ng new my_app anf after that executed ng serve from project folder.

Comment: what is the version of typescript in your local project and global?

Comment: typescript version 2.2

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a browser issue.I have updated my chrome browser it is working now.